# UIWebView: How to resize a taken photo (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview, camera

Consider my application a webView displaying my website. In my website I have an **input tag** where to upload a picture. This input tag on a tablet it is great because you can:

- upload an existing photo
- **take an instant photo and upload it**

The second option is the one that interests me. The problem is that there is **no resizement** and the picture sent to the server is **1MB (actual size)**.

I need that before sending the picture to my server, my application does:

- option A: after taken the photo this options are available

[image]

- option B: automatically the application takes a small photo (already resized)
- option C: do you have any other ideas?

Is it possible to do something to resolve this problem? **I am developing using SWIFT language.**

**Thank you**

Comment: For **Option B**, which I would use because it gives you the most control, you could take the NSData of the UIImage, make it a jpeg, and then lower its quality with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to reduce its file size. Check the Apple Docs here (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW9). In addition, you could resize the image as you suggested.